# Connected to vpn but can't connect to internet

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking, vpn, iptables

I am using ubuntu 12.10 as a vps. And I am trying to configure a vps server on it. I can connect to the vpn but just can't get internet access. Maybe because I don't know how to write a iptables.

```
ifconfig eth0
inet addr:162.251.120.98  Bcast:162.251.120.127  Mask:255.255.255.224
```

Please somebody write a working iptables rule for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try those rules:

```
iptables -I INPUT -p 47 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

iptables -I OUTPUT -p 47 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --sport 1723 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

iptables -I OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 1723 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```